# Angular Js Error Adding Angular Module

Tags: angularjs

I want to implement the application here,

http://plnkr.co/edit/tOow1cCjrGiXxpeT3EXZ?p=preview

Firstly, I use this application layout.html,

```
<script src="/Content/scripts/angular/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.7/angular-animate.js"></script>
<script src="http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls-0.14.3.js"></script>
```

Secondly,
My angular js module layout.html,

```
var appModule = angular.module("app", ["ui.router", "directives", "constants", "services", "oc.lazyLoad", "ngCookies", 'ngAnimate', 'ui.bootstrap', 'ngSanitize', 'mgcrea.ngStrap']);
```

I use HTML,

```
<div style="height: 305px">
<uib-carousel interval="myInterval" no-wrap="noWrapSlides">
    <uib-slide ng-repeat="slide in slides" active="slide.active">
        <img ng-src="{{slide.image}}" style="margin:auto;">
        <div class="carousel-caption">
            <h4>Slide {{$index}}</h4>
            <p>{{slide.text}}</p>
        </div>
    </uib-slide>
</uib-carousel>
```

```
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-6">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-info" ng-click="addSlide()">Add Slide</button>
    <div class="checkbox">
        <label>
            <input type="checkbox" ng-model="noWrapSlides">
            Disable Slide Looping
        </label>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="col-md-6">
    Interval, in milliseconds: <input type="number" class="form-control" ng-model="myInterval">
    <br />Enter a negative number or 0 to stop the interval.
</div>
```

Google Console Error Messages:

```
Error: [$compile:ctreq] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.3.14/$compile/ctreq?p0=carousel&p1=slide
at Error (native)
at http://localhost:17384/Content/scripts/angular/angular.min.js:6:417
at D (http://localhost:17384/Content/scripts/angular/angular.min.js:56:98)
at A (http://localhost:17384/Content/scripts/angular/angular.min.js:59:241)
at http://localhost:17384/Content/scripts/angular/angular.min.js:66:193
at http://localhost:17384/Content/scripts/angular/angular.min.js:112:20
at l.$get.l.$eval (http://localhost:17384/Content/scripts/angular/angular.min.js:125:305)
at l.$get.l.$digest (http://localhost:17384/Content/scripts/angular/angular.min.js:122:398)
at l.$get.l.$apply (http://localhost:17384/Content/scripts/angular/angular.min.js:126:58)
at http://localhost:17384/Content/scripts/angular/angular.min.js:138:243
```

Comment: Could you please update your plunkr?

Comment: Don't use the minified version of angular during development. Use it in production. You'll have much better error messages with the non-minified version. Your message indicates that you're using angular 1.3.14, and you're also using angular-animate 1.4.7. That can't work.

Comment: I updated link. And ı use angular min js 1.4.7 version in local.

Comment: The plunkr you've posted works fine.

Comment: Yes there is working fine but my application gives an error

Answer (score 0):

This error occures mainly when a directive has some required things, and you missing one: https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$compile/ctreq

Carousel needs a controller, and the HTML above, I don't see if you already defined one. Maybe you missing the controller for the page?